# Remove White Space above Footer?

Tags: css, padding, footer

On the home page of my website (and for all subsequent pages) http://www.ininkk.com, I was wondering if anyone knew how to get rid of the white space inbetween the image gallery and where it says "Privacy Policy, FAQ, and Our Story"?

I tried using the following code but it didn't work for me:

```
#wrap > div.container {
padding-bottom: 0px;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your height on the web page for footer is 311px. Reduce that and check that should remove the extra spacing [image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks, Sanket!